# strange behaviour of javax.swing.Timer

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

in main if the following code is used

```
Timer timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("boo");
    }
});

timer.start();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

boo will be printed every 200 milliseconds as expected.

While

```
Timer timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("boo");
    }
});

timer.start();
```

nothing will be output!

Comment: A javax.swing.Timer only will work if the Swing event thread is running. If you try to run timer without a Swing event thread, it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the code you're showing is in `main()`. When `main()` returns, the program exits before the timer thread has a chance to get going. The sleep gives the JVM enough time to create the other thread, which then allows the JVM to keep running.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the `Thread.sleep` is on the `main` thread and that the reason nothing is printed in the second case is that the `main` thread goes away and the program exits?

Answer (score 1):

Is that the complete program (is that the only code in your `main` method)? If yes, then in the second case the program ends before the timer goes off, so it won't print anything, because the program is finished almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

1) this code wokrs and in all cases is correct

```
Timer timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("boo");
    }
});    
timer.start();
```

you have to check if [javax.swing.Timer#setRepeats()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats%28boolean%29) have true value (default value), if isn't changed, otherwise you have a code that block [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), thenafter `Swing's Timer` too,

2) don't use `Thread.sleep(int)` during EDT, and untill Sleep ended caused this code block for EDT,